# iOS9 coloring and visibility issue

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9

I released an app today and it works great on iOS8.4 but on devices with iOS9 it performs a strange bug. When game is reaching game over scene it should show a score label and a highscore label. Highscore is doing fine, when score is showing from time to time. I couldn't find out what forses my score to do so. Here is my code from `GameOverScene`, if it helps:

```
var scoreLbl = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Gulim")

scoreLbl.text = "0"
    scoreLbl.fontSize = 150
    scoreLbl.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
    scoreLbl.colorBlendFactor = 0.8
    scoreLbl.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    scoreLbl.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(scoreLbl)

var score : Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("overScore")
    println("overScore appears \(score)")
    self.scoreLbl.text = String(score)
```

Also, as I understand iOS doesn't support `colorBlendFactor`? Because it works on iOS 8 with that score and shows plain red color on iOS9.

On iOS 8 it works like this [image: like this]

And on iOS 9 it islike this: [image: pic]

How can I fix that? Coloring **and** visibility.

Comment: I tested something and found  `colorBlendFactor` works for `SKSpriteNode` (it has "texture"), but not `SKLableNode`. Maybe try to use `alpha` to adjust the look of your score label? And I can't reproduce the problem of the missing `scoreLbl`. How do you add the highscore label on screen?

Comment: @WangYudong I think I managed visibility problem, it was wrong zPosition. And thanks for alpha suggestion, it helps!